# Wordpress custom permlinks to other page

Tags: wordpress

How can set permlinks to different page in wordpress?

like this `www.abc.com/blog.php?id=123`

instead of `www.abc.com/?id=123`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this.
I modified link_template.php in include directory of wordpress at line 161

in the function

```
home_url('?p=' . $post->ID);
```

I simply put

```
home_url('blog.php?p=' . $post->ID);
```

this works only with default permlink option in Permalink Settings.